# Conditional typedef depending on "platform"

Tags: c++

Suppose I write a function with the following declaration:

```
void sumAllBytes(const ByteArray& bytes);
```

I will use Qt as an example because that's what I'm familiar with; but I am asking about the general concept.

For those familiar with the Qt framework, it provides a `QByteArray` class.  I want my code to be able to work with and without the Qt framework.  Thus, with the Qt framework, the above function should accept a `QByteArray`.  Without the framework, it should use my own implementation (assume I have the same fundamental API).

In the past, I have solved this problem by doing the following:

```
//In ByteArray.hpp
#ifdef USING_QT

#include <QByteArray>
using ByteArray = QByteArray;

#else

#include <MyByteArray.hpp>
using ByteArray = MyByteArray;

#endif
```

If I were to compile my `sumAllbytes` function into a static library, I would then compile one version that works with Qt and one that works with other platforms.

My question is, are there any alternative ways to handle this type of problem?

Comment: Just asking for a "better way" makes this a difficult question to answer. Is there a problem with the solution you already have?

Comment: @GregBurghardt What I really meant was "alternative options" to help me get a full understanding.  I rephrased my question.

Comment: Asking for alternative ways is also way too broad for this community. Questions work best when the community can identify a single answer. Asking for alternatives means you can have 10 people answer with different alternatives, with each alternative being equally correct. That does not fit the Q&A format of this site. If you are really looking for general feedback consider a forum-style community instead. StackExchange sites, including this one, are likely to close this question as needing focus.

Comment: For things like ByteArrays, one option is to just ignore the framework. Only use the framework for things you _have_ to use it for, its unlikely to get you any significant benefit over MyByteArray, once you have paid the cost of having it for when you don't have Qt.

Comment: I had a similar "platform problem", as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609260/, also solved it myself using lots of #ifdefs like you, and then asked for a better solution in that question. "Sorry, Charlie" (or Patrick), apparently no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a couple of options here, but there's no silver bullet.

**Template/macro-like approaches.** This is what you're doing with your ifdefs. The point is that your code doesn't rely on any particular provider for this type, and is only compiled when a concrete type is specified.

Using C++ templates might actually be preferable over the C preprocessor, since templates can make it easier to specialize parts of your code for one concrete type or the other. Code for non-selected types can be disabled with SFINAE.

Alternatively, you can **abstract over the difference**. For example, you might create a `ByteArrayView` that can be implicitly constructed from both a `const QByteArray&` and a `const MyByteArray&`, and internally delegates to this source. One way to implement this for a fixed number of types is to create a tagged union of pointers (such as `std::variant<const QByteArray*, const MyByteArray*>`, or a pair of pointers for which you ensure that exactly one is non-null), but this will require forward declarations for those types. Alternatively, you can use dynamic dispatch based type erasure, with a template class that generates wrappers for all byte-array-like arguments. Prior art for this strategy is `std::function`.

In practice, those approaches require lots of boilerplate for little value, and greatly complicate your code base in order to deal with multiple possible types. It is often preferable to **convert to a common representation**. Your software system has components with certain boundaries. At those boundaries, convert data representation to a format that is convenient for you to work with. You can provide multiple potential conversions, which you may guard by ifdefs or templates.

Here, you just need a read-only byte array. The classic C representation for that would be:

```cpp
void sumAllBytes(const char* bytes, size_t len);
```

A C++ iterator-oriented API would take start/end pointers, or possibly be templated over an iterator type:

```cpp
void sumAllBytes(const char* begin, const char* end);


// or
template<class It>
void sumAllBytes(It begin, It end) { ... }
```

A C++20 solution might instead use `std::span` or `std::range`.

It could also be entirely reasonable to only support your own `MyByteArray` type. If a user wants a `QByteArray`, they will have to convert to and from your type. While that might be less efficient at runtime due to needing copies/allocations, the greater simplicity of the resulting code might be worth it – excessively clever code is where bugs like to hide.